# Re-using cluster_centers for another K-mean clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have a matrix of dimension (nw,ny,nx) where nx and ny are dimension of an image (photon counts) and for each pixel I have a spectral profile of nw wavelength points.

I have applied K-mean clustering from scikit-learn python package with number of cluster equal to ncl=5.

```
dat =dat1.reshape(nw,nx*ny)
mm[:]=KMeans(n_clusters=ncl).fit(np.transpose(dat)).labels_
x=KMeans(n_clusters=ncl).fit(np.transpose(dat)).cluster_centers_
```

and then plotting x[i,:] (i= cluster label) I can see the 5 different average spectral profiles generated by Kmeans. 
Now my question is the following: I would like to use these 5 cluster_centers in a different dataset of the same dimensions (nw,ny,nx) to retrieve the lables that here I have called mm. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you be more precise? Are you just asking for calling predict on new data? In this case it does not help that you throw away the cluster-object! You are calculating those clusters multiple times above! Make sure, you understand what you are doing there (and to understand the object-oriented approach of sklearn).

Comment: In addition to @sascha comment, since you are calculating the clusters multiple times, it may happen (usually happens when random_state in not set) that labels that you store in `mm[:]` do not match the clusters you get in second time.

Answer (score 1):

As @sascha pointed out, you need to persist the KMeans object to predict future data

```
dat = dat1.reshape(nw,nx*ny)
clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=ncl).fit(np.transpose(dat)

dat2 = dat2.reshape(nw,nx*ny)
dat2_labels = clusterer.predict(np.transpose(dat2))
```